# Python: Print string and number with a preferred number of decimal places in the same line

Tags: python, string, printing, floating-point, precision

I would like to print a string plus a float with a specified number of decimal places. In this case, 3 decimal places.

When simply printing the float, I specify the number of decimal places like this:

```
print('%.3f'% x)
```

The above returns what I expect.

However, when trying to include a string into the print(), I get a syntax error. This is how I am doing it:

```
print("The value of x is: " + str(%.3f'% x))
```

What is the right way of printing a string and float with a specified number of decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 27.0
print("The value of x is: {:.2f}".format(x))
```

prints:

```
The value of x is: 27.00
```

Good explanation here: https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is a formatting operator, meaning that you only specify one string, which you will latelly format with that operator:

Your string: `"The value of x is: %.3f"`

Format it: `print("The value of x is %.3f" % x)`

Note that for each `%` inside a string you will need as many values when using the `%` operator:

```py
example = "This %s formats %d times" % ("string", 2)
print(example)
```